# Perl use of uninitialized value in concatenation in module

Tags: perl, module, initialization, arguments, concatenation

I'm writing a module for simple emailing. I have default values that, if warnings is used, provide a use of initialized value in string error.

Code:

```
my %args = @_;
%args = map {lc( $_ ) => $args{ $_ }} keys %args;

my %email = (
    to => $args{to} || 'group@gmail.com',
    from => $args{from} || 'other.group@gmail.com',
    subject => $args{subject} || 'Message From System X',
    message => $args{message} || 'An empty message?!',
);
```

So essentially, if an argument is not passed.. use the default value. However, with use warnings turned on, I get the infamous

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
```

I'm sure it's something blatant that I'm missing.. but what is it?

Comment: What line is warning?

Comment: You're using the arguments logically, i.e. you're evaluating `$args{*}` when it might be undefined.

Comment: @Oesor, any argument that is not defined will warn. If all arguments are passed, there is no warning.

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? My first suspicion is that the actual code is double quoting the default values and that @gmail is trying to be interpolated, which is uninitialized, causing the error.

Comment: nothing in this code will generate that warning, as far as I can see.  show the code where the warning is occurring too, please.

Comment: @ysth, I don't think you're fully understanding. A script will pass parameters into the module and if a particular parameter has not been set, for instance if the subject has not been passed, then the default SHOULD be 'Message From System X' however, instead of defaulting to 'Message From System X' it gives me the warning on the line of subject => $args{subject} || 'Message From System X', and the only reason I posted this is because IT IS warning me.

Comment: and that line, unmodified, *will not* ever give that warning.  your code is something different than that.

Comment: @ysth, well then I guess I'm just lying and not looking for real answers.

Comment: no, you are mistaken about where the warning is given, or have some slight, but crucial, difference between the code you are showing us and the code giving the warning.  help us figure out what it is so we can help you.

Comment: still no progress?  can you boil it down to a self-contained example that anyone can run?  (doing so will probably help you find the problem, and certainly help us do so if you don't)

Comment: I used pre-validation instead. if ( $args{to} eq '' ) { $args{to} = 'group@gmail.com' }.. Full code will be here all day on 5/18 http://codeshare.io/kjUNK

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted isn't the code you're using. From your comments:

```
if ($args{from}) { print "\nFROM: $args{from}\n" } else { print "\nFROM: root@system.com\n" }
```

Since you're double quoting your strings, @system is being interpolated and concatenated into the string. It's uninitialized. This causes the error.

Comment: and the solution is to put \ before the `@`

Comment: Even using simple strings will warn with the code posted.

Comment: Actually, you will only get an uninitialized warning if `@system` *is initialized* with an undef element.

Comment: That error won't give the message the OP got. It will give `Use of uninitialized value in join or string`

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I thought older versions gave the OP's error instead of the 'Possible unintended interpolation...' but I just ran it through a system 5.8.4 and still got the same error as on 5.18.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the arguments logically, i.e. you're evaluating `$args{*}` to `true` or `false` when it might be undefined.

In strict mode, you would have to do something like this:

```
to => (exists $args{to}) ? $args{to} : 'group@gmail.com',
```

Comment: I've seen something like this before, however it doesn't seem to be a successful fallback and stop the warning, not that I would want it to.

Comment: This case is different as were testing for hash membership.

Comment: You do not need to do this under strict mode. `use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my %args = ( to => 'foo', from => '', subject => undef ) ;
%args = map {lc( $_ ) => $args{ $_ }} keys %args;

my %email = (
    to => $args{to} || 'group@gmail.com',
    from => $args{from} || 'other.group@gmail.com',
    subject => $args{subject} || 'Message From System X',
    message => $args{message} || 'An empty message?!',
);

p(%email);` does not warn, and supplies the default values for the missing keys.

Comment: @Oesor, unfortunately outside modules are not available on this system. However, this solution is working but not clean if ($args{from}) { print "\nFROM: $args{from}\n" } else {  print "\nFROM: root@system.com\n" }

Comment: Then replace Data::Printer with Data::Dumper.

Comment: and p() with Dumper()